# using toOrdinal to replace numbers with ordinals

Tags: regex, r, string, str-replace

I have a sequence of addresses and I am trying to replace numbers with ordinals. Right now I have the following.

```
library(toOrdinal)
addlist<-c("east 1 street", "4 ave", "5 blvd", "plaza", "43 lane" )
numstringc<-gsub("\\D", "", addlist)
numstring <-as.integer(numstringc)
ordstring<-sapply(numstring[!is.na(numstring)], toOrdinal)
ordstring
[1] "1st"  "4th"  "5th"  "43rd"
```

I want to eventually get a vector that says

```
[1] "east 1st street", "4th ave", "5th blvd", "plaza", "43rd lane"
```

but I can't figure out how to make that.

Comment: I'm guessing it would apply the ordinal indicator, i.e. "st", "nd", "rd" and "th".

Comment: more info on it: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/toOrdinal/toOrdinal.pdf

Comment: You would need a callback to construct that. Or simply create a new list by looping existing array and a find `\d+`

Comment: Thanks for trying. The numbers aren't all in front unfortunately. (I have updated my example to reflect this)

Comment: @LegalizeIt you shouldn't delete your answer.

Comment: @LegalizeIt I agree,  I was trying your answer just now!!

Comment: Looks like a handy package. You should mention it in the question, not only in a comment. A `library(toOrdinal)` line in the code would suffice

Answer (score 3):

With \\1 you can access the part of the matched expression in paranthesis, but gsub doesn't allow functions in the replacement, so you have to use gsubfn from the package by the same name, which actually doesn't need the \\1 part:

```
library(gsubfn)
addlist<-c("east 1 street", "4 ave", "5 blvd", "plaza", "43 lane" )
ordstring <- gsubfn("[0-9]+", function (x) toOrdinal(as.integer(x)), addlist)
```

Alternatively you can use gregexpr and regmatches, to replace them:

```
m <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", addlist)
regmatches(addlist, m) <- sapply(as.integer(regmatches(addlist,m)), toOrdinary)
```